# Is there any known implementation for unite testing using Mockito and Guice

Tags: java, unit-testing, dependency-injection, mockito, guice

I'm doing some unit testing using Mockito and DI using Guice. I want to implement a solution that allows me to switch easily between Production and Test mode. I didn't find any concrete example so I implemented my solution using my limited knowledge in those technologies.

First I created two AbstractModule

```
public class ProductionModule extends AbstractModule {
      @Override 
      protected void configure() {
          bind(DaoA.class);
          bind(DaoB.class);
          ...       
      }
}



public class TestModule extends AbstractModule {
      @Override 
      protected void configure() {        
          bind(DaoA.class).toInstance(Mockito.mock(DaoA.class));
          bind(DaoB.class).toInstance(Mockito.mock(DaoB.class));
         ...
      }
}
```

My Injector is a Singleton

```
public class GuiceInjector {
        private static GuiceInjector instance;     
        private Injector injector;

        private GuiceInjector() {       }

        public static GuiceInjector getInstance(){
            if(instance!=null) return instance;
            else{
                instance = new GuiceInjector();
            }
            return instance;
        }

        public <T> T get(Class<? extends T> cls) {
            return injector.getInstance(cls);
        }

        public void install(AbstractModule module){
            injector = Guice.createInjector(module);
        }
}
```

**Production mode**

So basically when the application start in production mode I install the ProductionModule and then I use GuiceInjector to get all the DAOs.

```
GuiceInjector.getInstance().install(new ProductionModule());
```

---

**Test mode**

For the test part, I set the TestModule as follows so that all the DAOs are mocked by the injector.

```
@Before
public void setup() {
    GuiceInjector.getInstance().install(new TestModule());
}
```

In case I want to invoke the real DAO, I use

`when(DaoA.getSomthing(...)).thenCallRealMethod()`;

Is there any known/better practice using Mockito and Guice ?

Comment: At the moment this question is too subjective -- it falls into the "primarily opinion-based" category.  Please rephrase it into a less subjective form.